# Php curl Scraping not getting all html content

Tags: php, curl

Php curl Scraping not getting all html content from  target link "https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/SearchProducts?search=Fresh%20Apple"
So please help me for scrape whole content

My source code is:

```
function getSslPage($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

}

$curl = getSslPage('https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/SearchProducts?search=Fresh%20Apple');

echo var_dump($curl);

Comment: it is working just fine. curl doesn't bring all the included, refered, etc, files in that page. It is not a browser. If you pass a link `https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/SearchProducts?search=Fresh%20Apple` that resolves to a file, lets say, index.php, the output from index.php is all curl will bring. All other gets to load images on that page, elements buitl/modified with js... nothing will come. But you can use the initial result to discover references and get them with further calls though.

Comment: I just need "https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/SearchProducts?search=Fresh%20Apple" total html content . So if you have a any idea , then let me know please

Comment: Isn't that what you've get? What is missing?

Comment: I've just tested... it is loading the html but apparently all "real" content is loaded latter with js so.. you can't scrape it like this.

Comment: have a any idea to skip that js? .... Hope then I can get original content

Comment: what I am trying to say is... the original content IS what you have now.
The page you see on the browser has all been loaded after with js.
So you really don't want to go around js but mimic js instead...